# Python - Merge two lists with a simultaneous concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, concatenation

```
ListA = [1,2,3]
ListB = [10,20,30]
```

I want to add the contents of the lists together `(1+10,2+20,3+30)` creating the following list:

```
ListC = [11,22,33]
```

Is there a function that merges lists specifically in this manner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> ListA = [1,2,3]
>>> ListB = [10,20,30]
>>> list(map(sum, zip(ListA, ListB)))
[11, 22, 33]
>>>
```

All of the built-ins used above are explained [here](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html).

---

Another solution would be to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Depending on your taste, you could do this:

```
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(ListA, ListB)]
[11, 22, 33]
>>>
```

or this:

```
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip(ListA, ListB)]
[11, 22, 33]
>>>
```

Comment: On my end I have to write `[k for k in map (...)]` to get it to produce the list, otherwise I get `<map object at 0x02380730>`, perhaps this is different for Python 3.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Yes, it is.  My apologies.  I didn't see the Python 3.x tag.  I updated my post.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, in Python 2 `map` returns a list, while in Python 3 it returns a generator object.

Comment: Maybe keep the list-comp more consistent with the `map` approach... `[sum(items) for items in zip(listA, listB)]`

Comment: The 'sum' function seems to not be working withs list items of string type.

Comment: @ArditS. - Yes, that is expected.  `sum` is normally used on lists of integers and/or floats.  Moreover, it does not support lists of strings. If you want to merge lists of strings, then my last solution might work for you.  Otherwise, I would recommend that you ask a new question to get help that is specific to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

@iCodez has given a great response, but in cases that apply to more complex situations and there will require a fair amount of manipulation (and concatenation) between lists, [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is a great and powerful tool to learn! This is how you would solve your issue with numpy:

```
#import it
import numpy as np
#state your lists as numpy arrays
array1 = np.array(ListA)
array2 = np.array(ListB)
```

that then sets up both of your lists as numpy arrays. Now all you do is add them!

```
>>> concatenated = array1 + array2
>>> print concatenated
[11, 22, 33]
```

Now this returns an instance of a numpy array, so if you want it as a list, you can just do `concatenated.tolist()`. As you can see, this is fairly useful when you are mapping mathematical operations across lists. There is a lot you can do with numpy and I suggest looking into it.

Note: I understand using numpy for solving such a quick simple problem is more exhaustive than necessary, but just in case this was a quick "how do I solve operations across multiple lists", numpy would make your life significantly easier!